# Need to take 2 values(prices) from 2 different onclick functions add then display the total in a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic

I am making a shopping website, my products page has 2 products, when the user chooses a quantity from the drop down list and clicks the add to cart button the product image,description,price,quantity and total price(quantity * price) is added to a table row at the bottom of the page. My problem is showing the total of multiple selected products. I have created variables that store the total for each product in their own functions. if a user selects the first product all the information i mentioned shows with the total price in a row correctly but if the user then selects the second product the information is added to the table but the total price is replaced by second product instead of adding totals of both products. Is there a solution?

```js
var count1 = 0;
var count2 = 0;
var count3 = 0;
var count4 = 0;
var quan;
var totalArray = [];
var priceArray = [13.99, 249.99];
console.log(priceArray);
console.log(priceArray[1]);




document.getElementById('btn3').onclick = function() {
  if (count3 == 0) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); //This adds a row after every click
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var product = row.insertCell(0);
    var desc = row.insertCell(1);
    var price = row.insertCell(2);
    var quantity = row.insertCell(3);

    count3++;

    product.innerHTML = "  <img src='images/mouse.jpg' id='img2' width='160px' height='200px'>";
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("desc3").innerHTML; //prints quantity
    price.innerHTML = "$" + priceArray[0] + " per item"; //prints quantity

    var selectedText = list3.options[list3.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var selectedValue = list3.value;
    quantity.innerHTML = selectedValue;


    document.getElementById('hcart').innerHTML = "Your Cart (1) Product";

    console.log(count3);
    var total = selectedValue * 13.99;
    totalArray[1] = total;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(total);


  } else {
    alert("Product already entered");

  }
};


//------------------------btn4-------------------------------------------------

var myQuantity;
var myPrice;
var total = 0;

document.getElementById('btn4').onclick = function() {

  if (count4 == 0) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); //This adds a row after every click
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var product = row.insertCell(0);
    var desc = row.insertCell(1);
    var price = row.insertCell(2);
    var quantity = row.insertCell(3);

    count4++;

    product.innerHTML = "  <img src='images/tab.jpg' id='img2' width='160px' height='200px'>";
    desc.innerHTML = document.getElementById("desc4").innerHTML; //prints quantity
    price.innerHTML = "$" + priceArray[1] + " per item"; //prints quantity

    var selectedText = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var selectedValue = list1.value;
    quantity.innerHTML = selectedValue;

    document.getElementById('hcart').innerHTML = "Your Cart (1) Product";

    console.log(count4);
    total = selectedValue * priceArray[1];

    console.log(totalArray);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(total);


  } else {
    alert("Product already entered");

  }
};
```

```html
<div id="prod2">
  <div id="img">
    <img src="images/mouse.jpg" id="img2">
  </div>
  <div id="desc">
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <p id="desc3">TeckNet TruWave technology: Provide precise, smart cursor control over many surface types. TeckNet CoLink technology: After pairing there's no need to re-establish pairing after a signal loss or shutdown.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="quan">
    <h3>Price</h3>

    <h5 id="p_amount3">CDN: $13.99</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="amount">
    <h3>Purchase</h3>
    <select name="quantity" id="list3">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btn3" value="Add to Cart">
  </div>
</div>


<!---Product4---------------------------------------------->


<div id="prod2">
  <div id="img">
    <img src="images/tab.jpg" id="img2">
  </div>
  <div id="desc">
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <p id="desc4">Samsung Galaxy Tab A SM-T350NZAAXAR 8.0 inch 1.5 GHz, 16GB, Android 5.0 Lollipop Tablet, Smoky Titanium. Keep All Your Samsung Devices In Sync. Connecting your Samsung devices is easier than ever. With Samsung Side Sync 3.0 and Quick Connect, you
      can share content and work effortlessly between your Samsung tablet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="quan">
    <h3>Price</h3>

    <h5 id="p_amount4">CDN: $249.99</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="amount">
    <h3>Purchase</h3>
    <select name="quantity" id="list1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btn4" value="Add to Cart" onclick="total()">
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>

<!--Cart------------------------------------------------->

<h1 id="hcart">Your Cart(Empty)</h1>
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="0" id="myCart" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h4>Name</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>Description</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>Price</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4>Quantity</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>


</table>
<div id="lists">
  <table style="width:100%" border="1px" id="table" height="10px">
  </table>
  <table style="width:100%" border="1px" id="table2" height="10px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h4>Total</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h4 id="total">Empty</h4>
      </td>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable say `cartTotal = 0`

Then, before 
`document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(total);`,
you calculate `cartTotal+=total` and then do

`document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(cartTotal);`

in both functions..
Here, the cartTotal will contain the total of all products added.